# Exp:resso Store and Authorize.net auth only?

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to run x_type "AUTH_ONLY" transactions from Exp:resso Store using Athorize.net AIM?

Reference link to Authorize.net x_type:
http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=3_TransDataReqs.06.3.html

Reference link to Authorize.net AUTH_ONLY transaction:
https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A64

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by navigating to Store > Settings > General > Credit Card Payment Method and selecting *Authorize Only* from the select box.

> If set to Authorize Only, you will need to manually capture payments before the funds will be transferred to your account.

This is however not gateway specific if you have multiple payment gateways in your store they will all be set to only authorize the transaction.